# Hide the arrows and dots - React / framer-motion-carousel

Tags: reactjs, carousel, framer-motion

I tried to hide the arrows and the dots, but I don't have success.

This is my code.

How can I do to hide the arrows, dots and to display the slides like a cycle? Some suggestions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRpCv.png)

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Carousel from 'framer-motion-carousel';

export default function DataStatusNacional() {

```
const slide1 = (
    code
);
const slide2 = (
    code
);
const slide3 = (
    code
);

return (
    <div className="w-full m-0 ">
    <Carousel interval={20000}>
            {slide1}
            {slide2}
        {slide3}
    </Carousel>
    </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

the carousel component have renderArrowLeft , renderArrowRight and renderDots props (void) you can do this :

```
<Carousel interval={20000} renderArrowLeft={()=>null} renderArrowRight={()=>null} renderDots={()=>null}>
            {slide1}
            {slide2}
        {slide3}
```